# Disability access at Kos

Tags: airports

I have bad knees and wonder if Kos Airport has air bridge or air stairs to board or disembark aircraft. Should assistance be requested.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not an airport has jet bridges, if a person is not able to easily walk stairs or walk longer distances, ask for assistance.
Explain what the person can and can't do, the staff at the support base can decide what help is needed and how to help.

My mother could still walk, if not as good as she used to do, and decided that she did not need that help but every body at the airports told her that she should have applied for assistance and that it would not have been a burden on them. (Having her walk slowly for quite long distances might have been.)

Even when an airport has jet bridges, sometimes you need to walk stairs to get on or off a plane, like when it is parked away from the airport building or when the jet bridge fails.